# Inside @GetMapping mapped method is it possible to fetch relative URL defined in value attribute

Tags: java, spring, get-mapping

In Spring web service, I have controller having multiple URL mapped method to handle requests. I want to map 2 urls to a single @GetMapping method like below:

```
@GetMapping(value = {"ex/{status}", "ex/retries/{status}"},  produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<ResponsePOJO> getExRetries(@RequestParam("interval") Optional<String> intervalOptional, @PathVariable("status") String successStatus)
    {
/**
*LOTS OF WORK
*/

//If this method was called via ex/{status} then call using true
getReport(true);
//BUT if it was called via ex/retries/{status} then call using false i.e getReport(true);
}
```

Now based on through which of the 2 urls this method was invoked, only change would be that in the last line method call will be with true otherwise false. Now if I implement 2 methods for those 2 urls mapping and **just change** **last  line** method call that would result in code duplication.

Is there a way to find which url was used to invoke it, then I can use ***if*** condition to make correct call and avoid 2 methods for it and hence code duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Add `HttpServletRequest` as an argument to the Controller method and than check the url.

Comment: Doesn't work - if I add a param in the method, result is 500 internal error : Failed to resolve argument 2 of type 'reactor.ipc.netty.http.server.HttpServerRequest' on public.  If mentioned lines are added ServletRequestAttributes sra results in null giving NullPointerException.

Comment: Sorry I wrote wrong class it should be `HttpServletRequest`. Also are you working withing a servlet container?

Comment: Doesn't work either. infact this time it fails before going inside the method call itself. Mine is springboot application using webflux but I am using RestTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not overcomplicate it.
You can have 2 methods which both call a third method that has a boolean parameter and contains **Lots of work** and getParameter(boolean param)

Comment: This duplication of code bugs me. I am sure some other developer would have faced it earlier and solution would have been sought as well. And yes this shouldn't be complicated but simple 1-2 lines that it.